# Glide URL-loaded images are reloaded in recycler view

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a recycler view which contains items with images that I have to download every time. This is the code for my OnBindViewHolder (adapter):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final BalancesAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Balance balance = balancesList.get(position);
    holder.tokenBalance.setText(balance.getBalance() + " " + balance.getTokenSymbol());

    if(Utils.loadLogos) {
        switch (balance.getTokenSymbol()) {
            case "ETH":
                holder.tokenLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ethereum);
                break;
            default:
                String imageURL = Utils.currentNokuUrl + "/logos/" + balance.getTokenSymbol().toUpperCase() + "-200x200.png";
                Glide.with(mContext).load(imageURL).listener(requestListener).error(R.drawable.erc20).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(holder.tokenLogo);
        }
    }


    SharedPreferences sharedPref = mContext.getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String settingExchangeRates = sharedPref.getString("EXCHANGE_RATES", null);
    if (settingExchangeRates != null && !settingExchangeRates.equals("Disable")) {
        String bal = balance.getBalance().replaceAll(",", "");
        switch (settingExchangeRates) {
            case "ETH":
                if (balance.getEthExchangeRate() != null)
                    holder.exchangeRate.setText(formatterFiat.format(Double.parseDouble(bal) * balance.getEthExchangeRate()) + " Ξ");
                break;
            case "BTC":
                if (balance.getBtcExchangeRate() != null)
                    holder.exchangeRate.setText(formatterFiat.format(Double.parseDouble(bal) * balance.getBtcExchangeRate()) + " ฿");
                break;
            case "USD":
                if (balance.getUsdExchangeRate() != null)
                    holder.exchangeRate.setText(formatterFiat.format(Double.parseDouble(bal) * balance.getUsdExchangeRate()) + " $");
                break;
            case "EUR":
                if (balance.getEurExchangeRate() != null)
                    holder.exchangeRate.setText(formatterFiat.format(Double.parseDouble(bal) * balance.getEurExchangeRate()) + " €");
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

The problem is that the list is dynamic, and when it is very large, and I return to the activity pressing the back button from a subsequent activity, the images are reloaded, creating a very ugly effect. How could I make it keep the previous image?

Comment: Can you share more code? At least the adapter code

Comment: I added the complete OnBindViewHolder code

Comment: In other words, you need to keep the main activity open in background, is it?

Comment: I don't think so, I only need to avoid reload the images, maybe using a cached copy

Comment: I guess, not only your images are reloading, your all adapter is reloading and a cause of this glide taking them from cache again. if your setAdapter method binded to activity's onResume somehow, move it to somewhere else. Also you can use Glide's override and thumbnail features, they helps a little bit too.